# Best of LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and of latest ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have many questions about this. I am well verse in using LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout, want to know best. **If some has reasons to use one of them.**

Some questions:

1. I think LinearLayout will add a hierarchy of nodes which will take more time to render than RelativeLayout or ContraintLayout, is it right?
2. Why android is considering `ContraintLayout` to use more than `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`? Even i can make same layout in `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies) article?

Comment: Not till, this is good one to understand. Do you thinks this have my answer best of these layouts?

Comment: I believe so, it also explains how android measures the layouts and the taxation system. In general `ConstraintLayout` offers more flexibility, and helps construct layouts without nesting, which affects performance.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i have get expected answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think LinearLayout will add a hierarchy of nodes which will take more time to render than RelativeLayout or ContraintLayout, is it right?

Nested `LinearLayout` widgets *can* be slower to render. It is not guaranteed that it *will* be slower to render. Using nested weights is one known way to get a slow set of nested `LinearLayout` widgets.

> Why android is considering ContraintLayout to use more than RelativeLayout and LinearLayout?

`ConstraintLayout` handles more scenarios than do `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. `ConstraintLayout` is easier for IDEs to support via drag-and-drop than is `RelativeLayout`.

> Even i can make same layout in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

There are a variety of scenarios that would be difficult to implement in `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, but that `ConstraintLayout` can handle easily, such as:

- Circular positioning
- Minimum and maximum size for the `ConstraintLayout` itself (to help `wrap_content` from getting too small or too large)
- Having a child maintain a specific aspect ratio
- Implementing some varieties of chains
- Anchoring children to artificial rules-based lines, such as `Guideline` and `Barrier`

Comment: I had my suspicions Google added `ConstraintLayout` to make UI design easier for iOS developers to cross over to Android UI design.

Comment: @Barns: That's very possible, though since I have done very little iOS development, I can't really comment on that.